# How to limit listview in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm working with `TListView` in `FMX`. At the moment i'm having live binding that's refreshing my `Dataset`, and i want to show only 10 or 15 items in my `TListview` from that `Dataset`. I tried with `Limit 15` in my query, but its giving me some unexpected errors.
Is there a way to control how many data are going to show on `TListView` ?

Comment: Beats me why this question was *upvoted* with such little information. A phrase like "unexpected errors" helps no-one; be specific, and show your code

Comment: I belive that part of the question is not relevant, thats why i just said unexpected errors, cuz it's not a good solution to limit my query. Question was about limiting listview, i still cant figure it out how to do it..

Comment: Correct. Write your query in such a way that it only returns 15 rows. In Firebird, this is `select first 15 * from`, in SQL Server this is `select top 15 * from`, in MySQL it's `Select * from <table> limit 15`. If you need access to all the items, have a second query with no limit for that.

Comment: I know for that solution, tried it and its not working in my case, its working usually but for me i just can't do job that's suppose to be done with  that solution, and that's why i am asking for any other limiting option with `ListView`...

Comment: Apparently there is no other way to do this. You need to limit your query and to handle listview by yourself making it via code and controling it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use LiveBinding, fill in a ListView with a runtime code.
This is a more flexible option.